# PHP PDF generation, error on $output

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a .PDF automatically, but for some reason. The PDF can't be created due to the PDF_REPLACE() syntax.

So this scripts works perfectly, as long as I don't trigger:

```
$output = pdf_replace("<<<opmerking>>>", $datum, $output);
```

The online code is here: 
http://073design.nl/peter/index_process.php

(In first instance, I missed the Function, but now I defined the function and receive still same error on the pdf_replace.)

```
<?php

$naam = 'Jan Janssen';

$datum = 'test';


//function define

function pdf_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string) {

  $len = strlen($pattern);

  $regexp = '';

  for($i = 0 ; $i<$len ; $i++) {

    $regexp .= $pattern[$i];
    if($i<$len-1) {

      $regexp .= "(\)\-{0,1} [0-9]*\(){0,1}";
    }
  }

  return ereg_replace($regexp, $replacement, $string);
}


//Generate the headers to let a browser choose correct application
header('Content-Disposition:  filename=dagstaat.pdf'); 

header('Content-type: application/pdf');


//open template
$filename = 'dagstaat.pdf';
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');


$output = fread($fp, filesize($filename));

fclose($fp); 

//replace the place holders in the template

$output = pdf_replace("<<<opmerking>>>", $datum, $output); // PROBLEM IS HERE

echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are getting?

Comment: use this services http://phptopdf.com/ it is very easy to use

Comment: @ K P: just click http://073design.nl/peter/index_process.php you'll see the error

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Thanks, this is a very valuable resource! I appreciate that. Regards. EDIT: Not useful for me as I don't want a paid third party resource!

Comment: Try using http://www.fpdf.org. It is a set of PHP classes for manipulating PDFs. And it's free.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a function named `pdf_replace()` but there is no such function in PHP and you haven't defined a function by that name. The PHP error you get (if you open the "PDF" file in a text editor) also clearly tells you the problem here: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function PDF_replace() in /var/www/vhosts/073design.nl/httpdocs/peter/index_process.php on line 24"

Comment: it's monday morning in Holland, and I think some weekend tequillias are still running through my veins. You are totally right, the function didn't exist! Shoot me